# Why does svg container break rect css?

Tags: svg, rect

So im trying to render these wave `rects` inside an svg container.

However the render only works when these rectangles are on their own (delete the svg wrapper). How can I get it working without deleting the wrapper.

http://codepen.io/zmwuqi/pen/BRrvjP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CSS supported by SVG elements is limited](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/propidx.html). Things like background-image are not in that list and don't work. SVG is not HTML.

SVG 2 will extend that list somewhat but still won't have parity with HTML.

When you remove the `<svg>` wrapper the `<rect>` elements stop being SVG elements and become unknown HTML elements. Unknown HTML elements are rendered (another difference with SVG as unknown SVG elements are not rendered).